# How to dynamically import icon / jsx element by string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on an icon selector at the moment. Once an icon is chosen, the selector returns the icon as a string, like `AirBalloon`. Then, I want to display that icon on my page, so I need to import it (I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabler-icons-react).
Normally, I would do it like `import {AirBallon} from 'tabler-icons-react';`.
So I tried this:

```
<IconSelector
    active={iconSelectorActive}
    setIcon={setIcon}
    additionalEvent={async () => {
        console.log(icon); // Logs the icon I selected
        setActiveIcon((await import('../../node_modules/tabler-icons-react/dist/icons/' + icon)));
        }}
></IconSelector>
```

But if I try to embed it into my JSX like that:

```
<Button
    onClick={() =>
        setIconSelectorActive(!iconSelectorActive)
    }
    variant="PRIMARY"
>
    {activeIcon}
</Button>
```

It throws the error `Error: Cannot find module './'` when I click an item from the selector.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the dynamic import, you can use `await import('tabler-icons-react')` then select the icon you need from the default export dynamically.

```js
<IconSelector
    active={iconSelectorActive}
    setIcon={setIcon}
    additionalEvent={async () => {
        console.log(icon); // Logs the selected icon
        const icons = await import('tabler-icons-react');
        const IconComponent = icons[icon];
        setActiveIcon(<IconComponent />);
    }}
></IconSelector>
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess that's the best way.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to import all the icons from the library like this:

```
import * as allIcons from "tabler-icons-react";
```

And then retrieve the selected icon by using its name like this:

```
const iconNameToBeUsed = "Activity";
const IconToBeUsed = allIcons[iconNameToBeUsed];
```

Finally render the selected icon jsx like this:

```
<IconToBeUsed />
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabler-icons-react-sj3kvv?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: This would definitely work, but I'm importing all icons to the end user. Is there a better option?

Comment: No, this does not mean `importing all icons to the end user`. React is a [single-page-application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) framework. When you use a dependency, whether you import one attribute or the whole package does not matter. They do not load dynamically from the server. In a single-page-application app, the whole project bundle (.css and .js files) is transferred to the client browser on initial request. Then all of the page interactions are managed on the client-side inside the browser.

Comment: Hmm, my nextjs page has about 90kb, but when i add the icons like you said, the page has 250kb+. Can i ignore that?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKilinc It *does* import all icons